# How can I make ultracopier handle cut-copy-paste function in nautilus?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, copy

I want UltraCopier to manage the copy instead of Nautilus.
When I open Nautilus, select a file or folder <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>X</kbd>), open another folder then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, I want this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

- [Homepage](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/)

Comment: http://ultracopier.first-world.info/

Comment: @Jorge can u please start a bounty on this question? I think its worth it!

Comment: @jorge thx for the bounty! its been almost 12 hours and still no reply! where are the pinguy guys??

Comment: @amith Have you tried Pinguy 11.04 alpha? I tried it and I can't get ultracopier in it also. See for your self: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/Pinguy.11.04.alpha1.png

Comment: @desgua so ultracopier is just a default app in pinguy 11.04 and is not default for copying! I guess we need some brilliant minds here to make it the default for copying!!

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/93231/is-there-any-special-software-for-copy-cut-like-operations/554813#554813

Answer (score 2):

There was a [dialogue](http://old.nabble.com/Ultracopier-integration-into-nautilus-td30437380.html) with the nautilus developers late 2010 but it fizzled out without a conclusion.

The developers said that the current nautilus infrastructure does not allow for the integration of ultracopier with nautilus.

It was mentioned, it should be possible via nautilus scripts - but those scripts cannot be invoked via keyboard - only via the nautilus menu.

Thus to answer the question - no - and not very likely.

Answer (score 1):

The version 0.3 is not ready to use (lot of bug, need be in beta, not in pre-alpha). But it have some improvement to help to integrate to other GUI, for windows a plugin just overwrite the copy handler and send the copy list via the catchcopy protocol. If nautilus allow overwrite copy handler it will be very simple to write a plugin to integrate Ultracopier.

Answer (score 1):

**How to integrate ultracopier with nautilus ?**

[image: ultracopier integration with nautilus]

1. Open software center and just search "ultracop", you will find two files for nautilus:

[image: Ultracopier in ubuntu software center]

- Advanced graphical file copy system(ultracopier)
- copy files on nautilus with ultracopier(nautilus-ultracopier)

install both of them and log out and login. Done! whenever you copy or cut you will get "Paste with UltraCopier" option in nautilus context menu

**for nemo users:**
install

- Advanced graphical file copy system(ultracopier)
- copy files on Nemo with ultracopier(nemo-ultracopier)

Comment: Ultracopier extension for nautilus no longer works per this comment: https://github.com/lestcape/Nautilus-UltraCopier-Extension/issues/1#issuecomment-254019464

Answer (score 0):

For that, ultracopier wait and listen copy with catchcopy protocol, the version 0.3 will be better to intergrate into gnome. For that's, gnome (nautilus), need send copy to software compatible with catchcopy protocol (like ultracopier).

Comment: @user13878 u mean i've to use version 0.3...can i get the deb link?? so they use 0.3 in pinguy 11.04??

Comment: No deb, since all the distro do them self the package, just ask to your distro to use it.

Comment: I have work (2 week ago) with the dev of nautilus. It's possible that into few time we have an integration.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution of edward torvalds, don't work right now(the repo is disable).**

I'm the author of this extensions and also who packs it on launchpad. So, please contact me if you have any problem. I appreciate a user feedback, to make the extensions better.

My first answer was delete by https://askubuntu.com/users/59676/mitch as a duplicate of this one(So find my posted in this location):

[Is there any special software for copy,cut like operations?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93231/is-there-any-special-software-for-copy-cut-like-operations/554813#554813)

If this continues happend i will to remove the extension for launchpad and package for other distros only...