# Multi-Threaded File Copier?

Tags: files

I am looking for a multi-threaded file copy program. The reason I'm interested in mult-threading is that I have 240 GB of files (most being pretty small) I need to transfer.

In Windows land there is Robocopy, Richcopy, Teracopy, etc. In Linux I can't seem to find any tool that can do this.

Is there any tool you all are aware of that does multi-threaded file copying?

Comment: wouldn't multi-threading i/o be bad?  Just curious.  HDDs can only do one thing at a time, which is different from CPUs which can run many commands at once.

Comment: I agree, if I try to have my computer do two different hard drive-intensive tasks, I thrash my hard drive and it can't do either task very well or much of anything. It can get so locked up that I have to reboot, so no, you do not need multi-threaded file copying.

Comment: @user1974 @jbicha I have found a definite speed increase when using multi-threaded file copying programs. There is though a wall at around 3-4 threads where any more and your just slowing things down. I also have to ask if this was proven wrong, why are there so many programs that do this?

Comment: What about rsync? Do not know if it is multi-threaded but it can resume.

Comment: rsync is highly unoptimized, the fastest it can do on a modern cpu core is 250mb/sec. 
I can do 1.6 GB/sec using "cp" and 250mb/sec using rsync

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [ultracopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/) - teracopy alternative you can use in ubuntu, windows and mac! I've been trying to get an answer for my question on how to make this the default app [how can i make ultracopier handle cut-copy-paste function in nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33461/how-can-i-make-ultracopier-handle-cut-copy-paste-function-in-nautilus) But its still pretty useful if you have large number of files and have to copy them to multiple destinations or need to pause in-between copying!

Comment: I will defiantly have to try that

Comment: @TheLQ checkout the screenshot on my question(2nd link) - you'll get the idea! its almost like teracopy.