# Is there any special software for copy,cut like operations?

Tags: software-recommendation, clipboard

In windows there is "Tera-copy" for copy,cut and delete like operations. Is there is any software in ubuntu.
Because I am using ubuntu11.10 the default copy manager is hanging some times and very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative could be [Ultracopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/)

Comment: i have installed it but how to make it as my default copy manager

Comment: I don't know what do you mean with "default copy manager". What is your current "default copy manager"?

Comment: when i try to copy copy one folder to another folder ultracopier should do that operation but the unbuntu default copy program is running i want to change that to ultracopier

Comment: I guess you expect Ultracopier to replace Nautilus copy command. I don't know how you can do that, sorry. Maybe you should ask separate question for that problem

Comment: @zetah: they could create a [Nautilus Action](http://askubuntu.com/a/77285/3940) for that.

Comment: @Takkat: Yes, that seems like best option available

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `cp` command at the command line. It's much less likely to hang than the GNOME copy manager.

Comment: sorry i want any easy method like GUI

Answer (score 1):

This might not exactly be gui, but pretty close to graphic user interface. I use mc (midnight commander) for cutting coping and pasting files. It works fine with ftp and ssh and provides a stable interface for a file manager if that tickles your fancy.

mc is available on ubuntu universe repository and can be installed through the command `sudo apt-get install mc` .

Answer (score 1):

---

> Helps you to integrate UltraCopier on the Nautilus/Nemo file browser.

---

**After install:** Select one option

- Restart your computer(recommended)
- Logout and login
- Execute for:

  Nemo: nemo -q (save your work first)

  Nautilus: nautilus -q (save your work first)

**To configure your keyboard shortcut**

Rigth click on the desktop and then in Configure UltraCopier.

**To install on ubuntu 14.04:**

For Nemo:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lestcape/ultracopier-extensions
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install nemo-ultracopier

For Nautilus:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lestcape/ultracopier-extensions
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install nautilus-ultracopier

**To remove:**

> sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
>
> sudo ppa-purge ppa:lestcape/ultracopier-extension

For Nemo:

> sudo apt-get purge nemo-ultracopier

For Nautilus:

> sudo apt-get purge nautilus-ultracopier

**Report any problem:**

https://github.com/lestcape/Nautilus-UltraCopier-Extension

https://github.com/lestcape/Nemo-UltraCopier-Extension